# You must be logged-in to download this component, despite being signed in

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac, xamarin-component

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac (typically I use Xamarin Studio on my Mac) for iOS and Android development. I'm trying to create a new solution and add "Components" to my solution. I'm signed in to my Microsoft account but it's saying "You must be logged-in to download this component".

Is there a way to disable this or tell it that I'm logged in? Or is there some other account I should be logging in with that I'm not aware of?

It says my status is "Visual studio Community". Does that not allow use of components? It Xamarin Studio, the free community license allows use of components just fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be a bug. A few days ago I had the same issue and was able to "fix" it by:

Right click on the components directory

Select "Get More Components..."

A windows to authenticate appeared and after authenticating myself the components started working.

Hope this helps.-